# Table design for Payment Schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

We are developing a database that handles payments to people. The area I am focusing on at the moment, is the scheduled payment options. Basically, the system sends payments to people once every fortnight. So, every 14 days, on a specific day (Wednesday, at the moment), the system must process the payments and send them out.

So, an example. PersonA gets $10/day. Every two weeks, the system accumulates all payments for a person, sums them up, and sends out a payment.

So, after the first payment, the person gets $140 sent to them.

However, it's complicated by the way that, if the payment day falls on a public holiday, or a shut down period, such as the christmas leave period (24th Dec to 2nd Jan), the system must make the payment on the day before the public holiday, or shut down period, and process any future payments for that period.

Example:

Payment period is 1st June, to 14th June. The payments for this period will be sent on the 14th, and be an accumulation of all payments for the period... So, on the 14th, we do a payment run that collects all payments within that period, and sends it off. However, there is a company shut down period from the 10th until the 18th. So, on the 9th, the system must get all payments from the 1st, to the 14th (The building of these payments has been handled), and create the payment on the 9th. The next period (15th to the 29th) will work as normal.

The question is: Handling this payment schedule. It's been proposed that we create a schedule table, with all the periods. So, record one: Start Date = 1st June, End Date, 14th June. Record two has Start as the 15th, end of the 29th.. and so on. How far to go into the future? No idea. But... that seems odd to me. I thought that we just need one Schedule row, with a 'Effective Date' of the 1st of June, and a 'Duration' which say 'Fortnight', or something. Then, with .Net, or SQL, we can work out if we're on a 'trigger' date. So, the first trigger date would be effective date plus 14 days. If they then decided to change it from a Wednesday to a Monday (For example), add a new Schedule row, with the Monday date that the schedule becomes active, and when the system date hits that date, the new schedule becomes active. There would have to be some logic to handle this, but the basic concept of one row in the schedule date is my idea. Holding all future fortnight dates seems - odd.

Handling close down periods would be handled via an 'Exception Dates', type table, which simply holds public holidays and shut down periods, Basically, dates where payments can't be processed.

So, every night, a process runs. And takes the active schedule row, and works out if we're on  fortnight date matching that effective date (How?), and checks the exception table to work out if we need to trigger an early payment.

How we work out if we're on a payment date based on an Effective date, and then checking the 'period' may be tricky... But, surely storing all future fortnights is - wrong?

Here's a basic start to what I would LIKE to do.. but... not sure if it can handle the requirements:

This table holds the line for the schedule. Every time there is a change, a new row is added.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PaymentSchedule] (
    [PaymentScheduleId] INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate]     DATE NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDays]     INT  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_PaymentSchedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PaymentScheduleId] ASC)
);
```

This table holds the exception dates. So, a single day will have the same start and end date... A range will have a differing start and end date.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExceptionDate]
(
    [ExceptionDateId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
    [StartDate] DATE NOT NULL, 
    [EndDate] DATE NOT NULL, 
    [Description] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ExceptionDate] PRIMARY KEY ([ExceptionDateId]) 
)
```

And this could hold a history of payments, linked to the schedule that was used.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PaymentScheduleHistory] (
    [PaymentScheduleHistoryId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PaymentScheduleId]        INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_PaymentScheduleHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PaymentScheduleHistoryId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_PaymentScheduleHistory_PaymentSchedule] FOREIGN KEY ([PaymentScheduleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PaymentSchedule] ([PaymentScheduleId])
);
```

So, based on these early table designs... I'm not sure how to get it to work. I need to somehow work out if todays date is a trigger date, based on the schedule. Once that's working, I can add functionality to manage exception dates. Does this seem to be on the right track?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am playing with the concept of the single row solution... but trying to build a database so I can test it. The idea of a single row for the schedule, with an effective date, and a 'duration'. And then, a way to work out 'Is this a payment date' type function. But hoping this has been done before, and there's a model that someone can explain to me.

Comment: Sorry, didn't answer that correctly. I am busy building a database now to try my concepts... so haven't got a lot to show. Will add once I have a few create statements.

Comment: i think the single row idea with Effective date would be more efficient. Let's say you name it SchedulePaymentSetup with fields like  FirstEffectiveDate, OffsetDays (value like 14 in your example would be here), NextPaymentDate, LastPaymentDate. But you would have PaymentDateHistory just to log the dates for the Payments made. And of course you will have ExceptionDates for those dates that payroll would be shutdown and therefore done earlier.

Comment: This sounds pretty much what I was hoping for... How to work out (With SQL?) if we're on a trigger date, may be interesting?

Comment: Added early attempts on table designs...

Answer (score 0):

Your existing design looks fine to me.

The only reason I would consider using a table of schedule periods, with a separate record for each period, would be if the length of each period is effectively arbitrary. Given that the schedule periods follow a set of fairly simple rules, I wouldn't bother.

One other reason to set up such a table might be for the ease of use of other programmers, who don't want to have to recode the rules for the schedule period dates each time they write a query. One way around this would be to write a view that simulates such a table.

Comment: Yeah, a projected list of payment dates worries me, because the day might change. I agree it would be easier, and would only be 26 records per year. But, I am hoping to make it more configurable, using the attempt above. It will be harder though, and unless I can find s way to calculate if today I'd a payment day, then I might have to resort to a pre filed table.